# Setting primeng close icon to hidden for the p-sidebar

Tags: angular, primeng

I have not been successful at hiding the close icon for the p-sidebar. Probably something simple, but I've tried:

```
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="displaySideBar" position="left" showCloseIcon="false">
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="displaySideBar" position="left" showCloseIcon="hideIconVariable">
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="displaySideBar" position="left" [showCloseIcon]="false">
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="displaySideBar" position="left" [showCloseIcon]="hideIconVariable">
```

The last 2 example produced errors. Thanks for any help!

Comment: The last 2 should work correctly. 

Binding to a property is done using the square brackets indeed. Can you show the error message ? Maybe it's something to do with your imports

Comment: Can't bind to 'showCloseIcon' since it isn't a known property of 'p-sidebar'.

Comment: Is your sidebar actually working? Like setting the visible to straight up "true", does it show the sidebar correctly ?
Discard the rest of the properties all together (position/showCloseIcon).

Comment: I find that: <p-sidebar visible="true"> displays the sidebar without errors. Also, my two first examples in the OP also display without errors. But I do see the close icon (x) in those cases.

Comment: My best bet would be that you're using an older version of primeng, since the property was introduced recently according to this [commit](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/pull/6030), maybe you will need to upgrade the package

Comment: @abdullahkady - Yep you're right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You need use [showCloseIcon]="false". Because showCloseIcon="false" getting by string i think, you can check with console.log() :)